# Sending image using sockets with base 64 format by JSON

Tags: php, python, json, sockets, base64

I'm trying to send an image taken from the camera and converted to base 64 format to be converted into a JSON format. Everything is working fine except when I use the function of json.dump in python it adds \n to the image_64 base format, where in the server, it can't decode the picture properly- It's giving a blank image .

Python code to send the image :

```
import socket
import datetime
import json
import base64 , urllib
from cam import *

Signal = "200"
Date = datetime.datetime.now()


captureImage()
del(camera)
facechop('test_image.png')

image ='test_image.png'

image_64 = base64.encodestring(open(image,"rb").read())

print "----------------------------------------------"

try:
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('X.X.X.X', 20001))
code = json.dumps({"number": Signal, "date" : "{:%m/%d/%Y}".format(Date),     "image" : image_64}).encode('utf8')

client_socket.sendall(code)
receive = client_socket.recv(5012)
print receive


except Exception as e:
print("ERROR: "+str(e))
```

& the server code is :

```
 function checkMessageRecieved(){
    foreach ($this->changed as $key => $socket) {
        $buffer = null;
        while(socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 10240000, 0) >= 1) {
            $n = trim($buffer);
            $decodeJSON = json_decode($n, true);
            $number = $decodeJSON['number'];
            $date = $decodeJSON['date'];
            $image = $decodeJSON['image'];
            echo $number;
            echo $date;
            echo $image;


            $image=str_replace("\n", "" , $image);
            $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
            $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
            $data = base64_decode($img);
            $file = __DIR__ . "/../photos/public/" . uniqid() . '.png';
            $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
            print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
            $this->sendMessage(trim("Successfully done...") . PHP_EOL);

            unset($this->changed[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```